# drupal7 theme page creation

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have created home page in drupal.it's work fine.But I don't able to create other pages(like,service contact,client.) (home page and other pages are different).I have create page.tpl.php.I could create region in .info file? here I have attached my page.tpl.php file.Could you please any one tell me.( other page format like one leftcontent and 2 rightcontent structure.).
page.tpl.php:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
                              <header id="header">
                                    <div class="section clearfix">
                                    <div class="logo_left">
                                            <?php if ($logo): ?>
                                                    <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home" id="logo">
                                                            <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
                                                     </a>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                               </div>
                               <nav class="logo_right"><?php print render($page['header']);?></nav>

                              </div></header> <!-- /.section, /#header -->

                                    <div id="menu">
                                            <!--ul>
                                                     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                                     <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                                                     <li><a href="#">Client</a></li>
                                                     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                            </ul-->

                                            <?php print render($page['header_menus']); ?>

                                    </div>

                                            <div id="content">
                                                                                                                            <article>
        <div id="content" class="column">
            <?php
            $url = request_uri();
            if(strpos($url, "user"))
            {
            }
            else
            {
            ?>
        <?php if ($breadcrumb): ?>
          <div id="breadcrumb"><?php print $breadcrumb; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another file " page--front.tpl.php " for home page and other files can use page.tpl.php

you can set home page on "Default front page" by using below link

"admin/config/system/site-information"